# Match a value and return the cell below with 2 sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a problem with an Excel Formula.

I have Sheet 1 and Sheet 2. On Sheet 1 I have the values I want to match and on Sheet 2 the values I want to return.
I want to match a value from Sheet 2 to Sheet 1 and return the cell below this matched.

I tried with:
`=INDEX(Sheet1!B11:B264;MATCH(Sheet2!A3;Sheet1!B11:B264;0)+1;1)`, but it's not working.

I don't see the mistakes in formula.

Comment: What do you mean with "not working"? Do you get an error? The wrong value?

Comment: Another very common issue is that the `MATCH` does not work. As you are seeking an exact match (with the 0 switch), the value must be exactly the same (no trailing spaces or other hidden characters in text strings, and the exact same precision for numbers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Offset.  Also, anytime you reference a table or group of data, it's important to make the cell reference absolute.  You do this by putting ($) into the cell reference (ex: $B$11:$B$264).  An easy way of doing this is selecting the cell reference part of the formula and pressing F4.  Try this:

```
=OFFSET(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$11:$B$264;MATCH(Sheet2!A3;Sheet1!$B$11:$B$264;0));1;0)
```